# What kind of exception to throw?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, exception

This question might sound a bit stupid but here it goes.

I have two functions that can be called at any moment. The first function takes a snapshot, and the second one analyses the data taken from that snapshot. Of course if the user tries to analyse the snapshot before taking it, my application should throw an exception. I know the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` that is generally thrown when......there is an invalid argument, but that is not really the case. Is there any in-built exception for this kind of cases, or will I have to use `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sounds like an InvalidOperationException.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx

That said, if you can design your API so that you can't get in this situation, that would be better. Something like (pseudo):

```
public Data TakeSnapshot()
{
   // ...
   return new Data(...);
}

public void Analyze(Data data)
{
   // ...
}
```

Like this, there's no way to call them out of order.

Answer (score 16):

[`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx)?

Comment: "The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state."

Answer (score 8):

Why do you allow him to get it wrong? How about a method

```
 ISnapshot getSnapshot()
```

with ISnapshot having the analyze method. Or just analyze() which gets the snapshot if one isn't available

Comment: +1, I would go for this approach, make the problem disappear by requiring the code to actually have the snapshot before access to the method is given.

Comment: I do get your point, but maybe in this case is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [System.ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx)  *- The exception that is thrown when one of the arguments provided to a method is not valid.*